# I have 5 different images on prestashop but about 150.000 products, so now i have 22gb in product pictures

Tags: css, image, prestashop

I used a program called "emagicone store manager for prestashop" to automate the process of uploading products to my website. Most of the products, as they are chemicals, just have the company name as the picture, so i have sets of maybe 50.000 products witht the same picture.

Even the picture is only arround 11kb, this program uploads one picture for each product. I contacted the program developers and they told me is not a problem of the program but of prestashop, as its structure forces to make a picture for each product.

I would like to know if there is any way to have an automated process of redirecting products with the same image to only one image and erasing the rest of them

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop DB structure requires different **id_image** for each **id_product** and every **id_image** is a different file in the filesystem, so unfortunately this is not possible (at least without heavily modifying the core and the whole logic)